# How to check if a pdf page has a bookmark?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to check if a page in a pdf file has a bookmark and what is in that bookmark, I'm using "iTextSharp.text.pdf" for reading and manipulating a pdf, but I can't find a way to check if a page has a bookmark or not.

Pleas help
Thanks!

I've tried to get the bookmarks, but it gets me the  all collection and i don't know how to get for a specific page it's bookmark, i used this code:

```
public void Bookmarks(string pdfSourceFile)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfSourceFile, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(""));
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        foreach (IDictionary<String, Object> bmProperty in bookmarks)
        {

            foreach (var fileProperty in bmProperty.Keys)
            {

                if (fileProperty == "File")
                {
                    // need the edit the value of Key-"File". Will it be possible to alter the value using pdfwriter
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: any code you have tried?

Comment: I've tried to get the bookmarks, but it gets me the  all collection and i don't know how to get for a specific page it's bookmark

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the page for each bookmark from the Page key in each bookmark dictionary.

For example:

```
public bool isBookmarked(string pdfSourceFile, int pageNumber)
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(pdfSourceFile, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(""));
    var bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
    foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
        if (Int32.Parse(bookmark["Page"].ToString().Split(' ')[0]) == pageNumber)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader);
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> bk in bookmarks)
{
string bjj = bk.Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString();
```

Use This.