# How to check if a page is a section (sub-bookmar) with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, bookmarks

I'm using c# to split files and I need to split them by bookmarks then sections. I'm using this method because I thought that it would have returned true either if the page was a bookmark or a section but it doesn't work and I can't find anything online. Could you help?

```
public bool isBookmarked(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber)
    {
        var bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
            if (Int32.Parse(bookmark["Page"].ToString().Split(' ')[0]) == pageNumber)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```

EDIT: I think that my question hasn't been understood or, probably, I've asked it poorly. The point was to find a sub-bookmark (because a bookmark can have sections like chapters in a book can be divided in small section) not a bookmark. However, not a problem at all, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Link to orginal thread: [How to check if a pdf page has a bookmark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464627/how-to-check-if-a-pdf-page-has-a-bookmark)
Try this:

```
   public bool isBookmarked(string pdfSourceFile, int pageNumber)
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdfSourceFile, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(""));
        var bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
            if (Int32.Parse(bookmark["Page"].ToString().Split(' ')[0]) == pageNumber)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
```